# Open a PDF file on a remote machine with local app in Java?

Tags: java, file

When I run code like this in Mac os:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("open  testFile.pdf");
```

the Mac OS will run Acrobat to open the local PDF file.

How can I do it, when the file is on a remote machine?
`\\remoteHost\share\testFile.pdf`

I try to do that like this:
`Runtime.getRuntime.exec("open  \\\\remoteHost\\share\\testFile.pdf");`

but I failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("open  \\\\remoteHost\\share\\testFile.pdf");`

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)` just passes the String to the OS for it to handle it. So, if you want to run the command

```
open \\remoteHost\share\testFile.pdf
```

You have to pass it to exec(). Remember to escape the \ (replace every \ by \\)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open \\\\remoteHost\\share\\testFile.pdf");
```

Of course, the user running the program should have permissions in the remote machine. If you need to set another user, use the open program command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to directly specify the path of an SMB share while using the *open* command. If you want to use *open*, you would have to mount that share as a local directory. See http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/24/access-and-mount-an-smb-share-via-command-line/ for an explanation.

A solution like that would be pretty fragile though. If you want a more reliable solution, I'd suggest using JCIFS (http://jcifs.samba.org/) to download the file locally and then use

```java
Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
```

to open the downloaded file.

Comment: thanks! but i want to modify the remote file in local Mac os,so i can't download file locally